# Creating a default .toString() method

Tags: dart, tostring

I have a lot of JSON models in my dart project that I would like to have a string representation of. I know that I can override the `.toString()` method per class, but that feels like a lot of work to write basically the same thing a bunch of times. Is there a way that I can create a mixin or extention to override toString? Or is it better to use code generation? (I found [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/to_string), but it seems like it isn't maintained any more)

The string representation I am looking for is just a list of all parameters, for example:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  UserOver(
    this.userId,
    this.name,
  );

  int userId;

  /// The full name of the user.
  String name;

  factory UserOverview.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserOverviewFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserOverviewToJson(this);
}
```

should have the following string representation:

`User(userId: 1, name: "Name")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own question there buddy. Just create a base class and outsource it. It simple.

For example:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User extends BaseModel {
    User({
       required this.userId,
       required this.name,
    });

    int userId;

    /// The full name of the user.
    String name;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$UserOverviewFromJson(json);

    @override
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserOverviewToJson(this);
}
```

Create a base model class

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

    @override
    String toString() {
        return toJson().toString();
    }
}
```

Don't forget these

```
User _$UserOverviewFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(name: json['name'] as String, userId: json['userId'] as int);

Map<String, dynamic> _$UserOverviewToJson(User instance) => <String, dynamic>{
  'name': instance.name,
  'userId': instance.userId,
};
```

Now to use:

```
final cool = User(userId: 1, name: "Name"); 
print(cool.toString()); //{name: Name, userId: 1}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't realize I was that close to the answer. Thank you!